# Formatting problems in bibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex

I have the following problem. I'm in the process of compiling my work but strangely the bib is giving me some problem, see here:

Why are the entries from there on not formatted like above? What could be the reason for that?

[image]

The code i use:

```
\usepackage [round,authoryear] {natbib}

\bibliographystyle{autorjahrdidiDE}
```

My .bst https://pastebin.com/QBsVDfyb

My .bib https://pastebin.pl/view/e08a2139

Comment: Could you also post you .bib file? I guess the problem is an 'illegal' character therein.

Comment: Possibly a better fit at:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Some of your .bib entries are of poor quality and contain mistakes including

- missing commas to separate field, duplicate entries (e.g. pwc entry)
- incorrect/inconsistent capitalization of titles and authors
- incorrect field delimiters (e.g. schneider entry)
- entries with math symbols, but no math environment (e. g. Demerouti2004 has the title `title = {The impact of shiftwork on work{\mkern1mu}{\textendash}{\mkern1mu}home conflict,  job attitudes and health}` [I guess you want `The impact of shiftwork on work -- home conflict, job attitudes and health` or maybe even a `---`]
- inconsistent page numberings (most have `x--y`, some entries have `x - y`
- missing fields (e.g. abo2020 is missing journal+pages; the exported bib entries from the doi contains the journal)
- other issues (in Mustofa_2020 almost all authors are incorrectly abbreviated)
- incorrect URLs (e.g. who; any URL with an `_` outside an `\url{}` environment will cause the math mode to start)

I used a different bibliography style but these entries lead to the same mistakes. As a side note, if you set `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you do no longer need to escape characters like ä, ö, ü, ß, é, etc. in the bibliography.